# what is the solution for "urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError" and "requests.exceptions.InvalidURL" bugs in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, get-request

I try to send a get request to a website using the url address in pupose to find out what are the available web pages i can access. During that, while trying the code I wrote, I got this error massages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dembi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 434, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  File "C:\Users\dembi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\url.py", line 397, in parse_url
    return six.raise_from(LocationParseError(source_url), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: <Request [GET]>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dembi\OneDrive\Desktop\CyPros\projects\1 - WebAdsAuto\Main.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(Website.readingPage("https://dash.bidmind.com/dashboard"))
  File "C:\Users\dembi\OneDrive\Desktop\CyPros\projects\1 - WebAdsAuto\Website.py", line 9, in readingPage
    response = requests.get(request)
  File "C:\Users\dembi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dembi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dembi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\dembi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 484, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\dembi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 368, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\dembi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 436, in prepare_url
    raise InvalidURL(*e.args)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: <Request [GET]>
```

I tried this: "pip3 install six==1.15.0". The upgrade was seccesful but it still sends those errors.

This is the code itself:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Website:
    @staticmethod
    def readingPage(url: str) -> list:
        pages = []
        request = requests.Request("GET", url)
        response = requests.get(request)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            for page in soup.select("tbody tr"):
                pages.append(page)
        else:
            print("Error: " + str(response.status_code))
        return pages

print(Website.readingPage("https://dash.bidmind.com/dashboard"))
```

Comment: (1) Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. (2) Show the relevant code (better an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) as properly formatted in the question.

Comment: Without the relevant Python code fragment it's difficult to know what's going on here

Comment: so sorry, i thought i uploaded it. Now it appears.

Comment: `requests.get` expects a URL, not a `Request` object.